# How to find out whether a shot ended up in a goal in the Wyscout Dataset

Tags: python, dataframe

So I am trying to filter the Wyscout Dataset. Example:

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

And the thing is I can't find if a shot is a goal or not.

This is the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('events_England.csv')

shots = df[df.eventName=='Shot']
data = shots[['subEventName', 'pos_orig_x', 'pos_orig_y', 'pos_dest_y', 'pos_dest_x']]
```

To explain the 'event' is supposed to be the shot attempt, end the goal should be a 'subevent'.

An image of the resulting Dataframe:

[image: screenshot of table]

And I can't find the 'Goal' subEventName in order to change it to a binary value.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: Since this is the same group as statbomb, I assume the same data layout and comment. There is a shot in the event data, and the next layer has a classification of results, classified as 97/"Goal". The rationale is taken from page 20 of [this document](https://github.com/statsbomb/open-data/blob/master/doc/Open%20Data%20Events%20v4.0.0.pdf).